# .pcm is out of date and needs to be rebuilt

Tags: macos, cocoalumberjack

Since updated my mac to OSX10.12, I have got this error:
[image]

And I must clean, otherwise the build will fail.

I have googled a lot, but did not found useful solution.
I am wondering about the .pcm files. 
hope some person could help. Thanks.

Comment: We’ve been getting this error regularly now since updating to Xcode 12.5, but it’s not clear what is triggering it.

Comment: This won't probably help anyone, but I'll write it anyway.
 we had this since having a very specific dependency tree. Unit tests ("child" of the app target) target depended on a subspec (cocoapods) of the the main target's dependency - main depended on LibA and unit tests LibA/TestsHelpers). Worst, it only failed the very first time after a clean/deleting derived data. In the end what made it go away was to set "precompile bridging header" to NO.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got this issue once. Here are the steps of what worked for me:-

1. Getting the path for the derived data folder in Finder from Xcode.
2. closing Xcode
3. deleting the derived data folder from finder
4. emptying Trash
5. Reopening Xcode
6. Cleaning and building again.

Hope this helps you as well...

Comment: If you are seeing this in React Native, just delete the build folder and run `react-native run ios` again.